# ValueError Exception

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

The problem I am trying to solve seems simple: take 2 integer inputs, user_num and div_num, and divide them then catch the exceptions using try/except blocks. language is **python**.

for division by zero, output this: **Zero Division Exception: integer division or modulo by zero**

Assuming input of user_num=15.5 and div_num=5, for ValueError, output this: **Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '15.5'**

the problem gives us this as well: Note: ZeroDivisionError is thrown when a division by zero happens. ValueError is thrown when a user enters a value of different data type than what is defined in the program. Do not include code to throw any exception in the program

the calculation and divison by zero work as intended but my ValueError exception does not work. I understand the error (I defined an integer but gave it a float) but I am stumped as to how to make the program do what I need it to. Here is what I have:

```
user_num=int(input())
div_num=int(input())

try:
    print(int(user_num/div_num))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Zero Division Exception: integer division or modulo by zero")
except ValueError:
    print("Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10:", user_num)
```

the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    user_num=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '15.5'
```

any help would be appreciated to make the ValueError exception work

Comment: You need to put that `try/except` around the `input()` calls, not the division.

Comment: The traceback shows that the error is triggered by the conversion, which is outside of the try block.

Comment: that fixed it, thank you so much! I understand this better now

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for anyone that comes across this, this is what I managed to get working. The error is because of the initial (int(input()) there is not any error handling in place when first inputting the value. Below is what I found to work and handle anything I ran across with it. it first tries to convert the strings into ints. If it can't that is when it will throw the errors instead of at the start. I'm sure it could be a bit cleaner but I am still fairly new to programming.

```
user_num=input()
div_num=input()
try:
    print('{:.0f}'.format(int(user_num)/int(div_num)))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Zero Division Exception: integer division or modulo by zero")
except ValueError:
    pass
try: int(div_num)
except ValueError:
    print("Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"+" 
'"+str(div_num)+"'")
try: int(user_num)
except ValueError:
    print("Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"+" 
'"+str(user_num)+"'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this one to work:

```
try:
    user_num = int(input())
    div_num = int(input())
    print(user_num // div_num)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Zero Division Exception: integer division or modulo by zero')
except ValueError as excpt:
    print('Input Exception: '+str(excpt))
```